# M. Artin, Algebra, Chapter 2, exercise 4.11.(a)

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetric-groups

**Adapt the method of row reduction to prove that the transpositions generate the symmetric group $S_n$.**

I can prove the theorem that *transpositions can generate $S_n$* but Artin asks to adapt row reduction. I don't know what he means. Kindly help to understand this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every permutation of $S_n$ can be written as a permutation matrix in the group $GL_n(K)$, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix). For these matrices, do row reduction.

Comment: thank you! I can solve now